# Preventing misinformation: Correcting the usage of the term "JSON object"

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, question-quality

Unfortunately there is a confusion between [JSON](http://json.org/) and the [JavaScript syntax construct commonly known as "object literal"](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5).

To be clear what I mean, this is JSON:

```
{"foo": 42}
```

This is an JS object literal:

```
var obj = {"foo": 42};
```

This is JSON in JS (it's a string):

```
var obj = '{"foo": 42}';
```

Syntactically the difference might be subtle, but technically they are two totally different things (I sometimes ask what `v = {"foo": 42}` is, and after clarifying that this is a *Python dictionary*, people seem to understand that it is not JSON, even though it looks like it).

Now, there are many questions which ask about how to do something with "JSON" or a "JSON object", even though the question is really about how to work with JS objects. Here are some example:

- [Concat JSON objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/433627/218196)
- [Add new attribute (element) to JSON object using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/736590/218196)
- [How to get JSON objects value if its name contains dots?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2577172/218196)
- [JSON objects .. inside JSON objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7031465/218196)
- [Appending to an object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/617036/218196)

In some cases the answers pointed out the mistake and explained what JSON is.

Sometimes questions really seem to contain JSON, or it is explicitly stated that JSON is received from an Ajax call, but at its core the problem has still nothing to do with JSON, *where/how* the data was received usually does not matter:

- [Sorting a JSON object in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4222690/218196)
- [get size of json object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6756104/218196)

So, my questions are:

1. Should we edit and correct existing questions, even though it would make some answers (partially) obsolete and bump very old questions to the top?
2. What about those questions that contain JSON but are still about processing the data in JavaScript?
3. Or should we let it all be so that ignorant users still find for what they are looking for?

Comment: Can we nail `jQuery variable` while we're at it? (ducks)

Comment: Oh, and if-loops?

Comment: @Tim: The confusing between jQuery and JavaScript is a similar (maybe even more important) issue. This might even bring us in a conflicting situation: Do we want questions to be technically correct or do we want people to find questions/answers more easily (which might require the usage of incorrect terms, because they use it)?

Comment: @JoachimSauer: [I use if-loops all the time!](http://pastebin.com/pP4KJnTe)

Comment: I think a good course of action would be to retag (not edit) and leave a comment, explaining what the difference is.

Comment: ***FOURTY TWO!*** Slowly I turned... step by step.... inch by inch.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Churn isn't as big of a concern as you might think, especially today. Two years ago a bunch of edits to very old questions would have resulted in the front page looking like an antique store for a while, but our current question volume *mostly* eliminates that problem. Old content that still has value *should* churn every now and then so folks remember it exists and needs maintaining.

This is a misnomer that should probably be corrected so that unchecked existence doesn't continue to perpetuate and validate it, and why we have edit privileges. You have two straight forward options where the only consideration is the misuse of terminology:

- Edit the question to correct this, *provided* that it doesn't obfuscate the problem that the question is describing (if someone is treating a string like an object, you can't correct that), ***or***,
- Edit the top answer to contain a brief, reusable correction

Questions that contain JSON but are still about processing the data using JS can be tricky, and I share your concern that changing these too much would probably make great information harder to find for beginners. In these cases, I suspect that adding additional correction / clarification to the top answer (if lacking) is probably going to be your best bet.

Is this worth doing? Yeah - if we managed to contain squiggly all those years ago we'd still have tildes. We may not be able to get search engines to throw a *did you mean ...?* when someone types 'JSON object', but we can surely do our best to not get in the way of it.

Just be careful to not alter the *intent* of any posts, but I see this as doing what we're supposed to be doing as curators of the contributions that we've been so graciously given.

Comment: Thanks Tim! It's not always easy to choose the right approach but at least I'm reassured now that I should correct the question if it needs to be.